# Gettings field values from within ACF groups

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to set up an opening hours solution using ACF.

Right now I have a field group that consists of 6 groups each 3 items. It looks like this:

Monday (group / name: mo)

- from (name: mo_start)
- to (name: mo_end)
- closed (name: mo_closed)

Tuesday (group / name: tu)

- from (name: tu_start)
- to (name: tu_end)
- closed (name: tu_closed)

etc...

I managed to display the names of the days in the front end, but I have no idea how to reach the values nested in the groups.

I tried it with get_fields, get_object, get_objects and I also tried the sub_field.

EDIT:
Thanks to Hristijan Manasijev I tried the following:

```
<?php
$field_group_key = 'group_123456789';
$fields = acf_get_fields($field_group_key);

foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field ):
    $NameOfDayShort = substr($field['label'],0, 2);
    $FieldName = $field['name'];

    if( have_rows($FieldName) ):
        while( have_rows($FieldName) ): the_row(); 
            // Get sub field values.
            $From = get_sub_field($FieldName."_from");
            $To = get_sub_field($FieldName."_to");
                        
            $Times = $From." - ".$To;
        endwhile; 
    endif; 
                
    $return_string_hrs .= $NameOfDayShort.": ";
    $return_string_hrs .= $Times;
    $return_string_hrs .= "<br />";

endforeach;
?>
```

But this also doesn't work. It doesn't even seem to go to the loop, as the variabel $Times comes back as "undefinded". The only output i get is the variable $NameOfDayShort, which is the "top level" of the group.

And another edit:

I did now a `print_r` of `$fields` and fount out the `value' fields of the sub fields are returned empty? How can this be? On the admin page the values stay stored

Answer (score 0):

To access group's subfields (also applies to repeaters fields, and flexible fields), you need to loop the group's fields. The ACF documentation contains a section about [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/#loop-example).

```
<?php if( have_rows('mo') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('mo') ): the_row(); 
    // Get sub field values.
    $mo = get_sub_field('from');
    $from = get_sub_field('to');

    // do your logic here...
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thansk for your help. I tried it, but it doesn't work. See above. I added my code